# ArangoDB 3.1 Query Explainer

Tags: indexing, arangodb, aql

When executing AQL against an indexed database, I find that my queries are significantly faster. However, the query explainer states that no indices were used. How can this be? Is it a bug? I run the same query in two identical databases, except that one has a variety of indices and the other has no indices. In the indexed database, the query takes 5 seconds. In the non-indexed database, the query takes 13 seconds. Both databases say that no indices were used when explaining the query, and provide identical execution plans and optimization rules.

#### Query:

```
let lastYear = left(date_subtract(date_now(),1,"year"),10)
    for v0, e0, in outbound 'myFleet' graph 'myGraph'
        filter e0.type == 'myType' && v0.attr == 'myAttr'
        let myCount = (
            for v1, e1 in outbound v0._id graph 'myOtherGraph'
            filter e1.category == "myCategory" && e1.date > lastYear
            collect with count into stuff
            return stuff)
        sort myCount desc
    return {profile: v0.name, count: mycount[0]}


Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType          Est.   Comment
  1   SingletonNode        1   * ROOT
  2   CalculationNode      1     - LET lastYear = LEFT(DATE_SUBTRACT(DATE_NOW(), 1, "year"), 10)   /* v8 expression */
  3   TraversalNode        3     - FOR v0  /* vertex */, e0  /* edge */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND 'myFleet' /* startnode */  GRAPH 'myGraph'
  4   CalculationNode      3     - LET #11 = (((e0.`type` == "myType") && (v0.`attr` == "myAttr")))  /* simple expression */
  5   FilterNode           3     - FILTER #11
 15   SubqueryNode         3     - LET myCount = ...   /* subquery */
  6   SingletonNode        1       * ROOT
  7   CalculationNode      1         - LET #13 = v0.`_id`   /* attribute expression */
  8   TraversalNode       10         - FOR v1  /* vertex */, e1  /* edge */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND #13 /* startnode */  GRAPH 'myOtherGraph'
  9   CalculationNode     10         - LET #17 = (e1.`category` == "myCategory")   /* simple expression */
 10   FilterNode          10         - FILTER #17
 11   CalculationNode     10         - LET #19 = (e1.`date` > lastYear)   /* simple expression */
 12   FilterNode          10         - FILTER #19
 13   CollectNode          1         - COLLECT  WITH COUNT INTO stuff   /* sorted*/
 14   ReturnNode           1         - RETURN stuff
 16   SortNode             3     - SORT myCount DESC
 17   CalculationNode      3     - LET #21 = { "profile" : v0.`name`, "count" : myCount[0] }   /* simple expression */
 18   ReturnNode           3     - RETURN #21
```

#### Indices

In the indexed database:

- `v0.attr` has: `{hash: {unique: false, sparse: false}}` with selectivity 0.08%
- `e1.category` has `{hash: {unique: false, sparse: false}}` with selectivity 0.00%
- `e1.date` has `{skiplist: {unique: false, sparse: false}}`

In the non-indexed database, the only indices are the defaults for document keys and edge identifiers.

In the indexed database, the query is significantly faster than the non-indexed database, but the query explainer on both says:

```
Indexes used:
 none
```

It is clear that the database is using the indices, but the query explainer won't say how.

Comment: Can you add your AQL query to the question, please?

Comment: No indexes are shown for the traversal parts of queries, though a traversal will always use an index (or multiple starting in 3.1). We're working on a fix for this.

Comment: That answers my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(note: just gave the same answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405191/arangodb-not-using-index-during-traversal) as the questions are similar)

In ArangoDB 3.0 a traversal will always use the edge index to find connected vertices, regardless of which filter conditions are present in the query and regardless of which indexes exist.

In ArangoDB 3.1 the optimizer will try to find the best possible index for each level of the traversal. It will inspect the traversal's filter condition and for each level pick the index for which it estimates the lowest cost. If there are no user-defined indexes, it will still use the edge index to find connected vertices. Other indexes will be used if there are filter conditions on edge attributes which are also indexed and the index has a better estimated average selectivity than the edge index.

In 3.1.0 the explain output will always show "Indexes used: none" for traversals, even though a traversal will always use an index. The index display is just missing in the explain output. This has been fixed in ArangoDB 3.1.1, which will show the individual indexes selected by the optimizer for each level of the traversal.

For example, the following query shows the following explain output in 3.1:

```
Query string:
 FOR v, e, p in 0..3 ANY 'v/test0' e 
   FILTER p.edges[0].type == 1 && p.edges[2].type == 2 
   RETURN p.vertices 

Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType          Est.   Comment
  1   SingletonNode        1   * ROOT
  2   TraversalNode     8000     - FOR v  /* vertex */, p  /* paths */ IN 0..3  /* min..maxPathDepth */ ANY 'v/test0' /* startnode */  e
  3   CalculationNode   8000     - LET #5 = ((p.`edges`[0].`type` == 1) && (p.`edges`[2].`type` == 2))   /* simple expression */
  4   FilterNode        8000     - FILTER #5
  5   CalculationNode   8000     - LET #7 = p.`vertices`   /* attribute expression */
  6   ReturnNode        8000     - RETURN #7

Indexes used:
 By   Type   Collection   Unique   Sparse   Selectivity   Fields                Ranges
  2   edge   e            false    false        10.00 %   [ `_from`, `_to` ]    base INBOUND
  2   edge   e            false    false        10.00 %   [ `_from`, `_to` ]    base OUTBOUND
  2   hash   e            false    false        63.60 %   [ `_to`, `type` ]     level 0 INBOUND
  2   hash   e            false    false        64.40 %   [ `_from`, `type` ]   level 0 OUTBOUND
  2   hash   e            false    false        63.60 %   [ `_to`, `type` ]     level 2 INBOUND
  2   hash   e            false    false        64.40 %   [ `_from`, `type` ]   level 2 OUTBOUND
```

Additional indexes are present on `[ "_to", "type" ]` and `[ "_from", "type" ]`. Those are used on levels 0 and 2 of the traversal because there are filter conditions for the edges on these levels that can use these indexes. For all other levels, the traversal will use the indexes labeled with "base" in the "Ranges" column.

The explain output fix will become available with 3.1.1, which will be released soon.